# What is linq for my query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an Entity Framework query that i want to change it to Linq,
my query is :

```
(from l in db.PageLayouts
 where l.ZoneName == zone.Name
 join p in db.PageLayouts
 on l.PageId equals p.PageId
 where p.ZoneName == PageName
 orderby l.AppearanceOrder
 select l).ToList();
```

is there anybody help me to convert it?

Comment: That is already Linq, no need to change it

Comment: yep, already in Linq format.

Comment: The entity framework query is already in linq syntax and thus a linq query. So either you are confusing things there in your question or you should explain a bit more detailed what you need to do there as currently it looks like you have already solved your own question with the questions content.

Comment: Are you looking for **LINQ & Lamda Expressions** because your posted code is already  linq query?

Comment: That's already Linq and it's in query syntax - I assume your looking for method syntax. @Jcl posted a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is already Linq. I'm guessing here, but I think you want to change it to fluent (or "method syntax"), if so, here is the direct *translation*:

```
db.PageLayouts.Where(x => x.ZoneName == zone.Name)
              .Join(db.PageLayouts,
                    l => l.PageId,
                    p => p.PageId,
                    (l,p) => new { l,p })
              .Where(z => x.p.ZoneName == PageName)
              .OrderBy(x => x.l.AppearanceOrder)
              .Select(x => x.l)
              .ToList();
```

I don't think your join makes a lot of sense, but I just changed the syntax from linq to fluent.

PS: this answer was crafted quickly and without thinking too much, handle with care

Answer (score 0):

We have Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ.See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx).

```
//Query syntax:
IEnumerable<int> numQuery1 = 
    from num in numbers
    where num % 2 == 0
    orderby num
    select num;

//Method syntax:
IEnumerable<int> numQuery2 = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).OrderBy(n => n);
```

> Most queries in the introductory Language Integrated Query (LINQ)
>   documentation are written by using the LINQ declarative query syntax.
>   However, the query syntax must be translated into method calls for the
>   .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled. These
>   method calls invoke the standard query operators, which have names
>   such as Where, Select, GroupBy, Join, Max, and Average. You can call
>   them directly by using method syntax instead of query syntax.